# Update dynamic JSON keynames

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an interesting situation that I am trying to wrap my head around. I have access to a `JSON` output that has key names which are numeric such as `_22` , `_155` etc. I created a mapping with what all of those key names translate to but I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to update the `json` and replace the original keyname with the one from the map.

Here is an example of my `json` string which contains the real field names:

The `FieldID` corresponds to the source `json` data, without the underscore.

```
[
{
    "FieldID": "7",
    "FieldName": "Emp ID",
    "IsSortableInput": "0",
    "IsFilterableInput": "0",
    "ViewAlias": "EmpID",
    "LogicOperator": "IN",
    "AllowMultipleValues": "1",
    "IsViewable": "1",
    "PrimaryOnly": "0",
    "DisplayOrder": "1"
},
{
    "FieldID": "3",
    "FieldName": "QID",
    "InputTypeID": "1",
    "FieldPlaceholder": "Enter Employee Name",
    "IsSortableInput": "1",
    "IsFilterableInput": "1",
    "ViewAlias": "QID",
    "LogicOperator": "IN",
    "AllowMultipleValues": "1",
    "IsViewable": "1",
    "PrimaryOnly": "0",
    "DisplayOrder": "2",
    "FieldTypeDesc": "PeopleSearch"
},
{
    "FieldID": "6",
    "FieldName": "NTID",
    "IsSortableInput": "1",
    "IsFilterableInput": "0",
    "ViewAlias": "NTID",
    "LogicOperator": "IN",
    "AllowMultipleValues": "1",
    "IsViewable": "1",
    "PrimaryOnly": "0",
    "DisplayOrder": "3"
}
```

]

My goal here is to loop through the source `json` string, find the key names in the map (defined json) and rename them. Ultimately replacing `_7` with `Emp ID` in my source json data.

**Source JSON:**

```
[
{
    "_3": "Q123",
    "_7": "E12345"
},
{
    "_3": "X123",
    "_7": "E34567"
}
]
```

Desired Output is to alter the source JSON, turning it into:

```
[
{
    "QID": "Q123",
    "Emp ID": "E12345"
},
{
    "QID": "X123",
    "Emp ID": "E34567"
}
]
```

I am pretty lost on where to even start with this approach. Not sure if key names can be renamed or if they need to be deleted in the process etc.

Looking for some suggestions on tackling this.

Comment: I would just recreate a new json file with the correct names.

Comment: @wvdz - Correct, that is essentially what I am trying to do by renaming the data. I do not have access to the source json to rename directly, I just have the names of the fields and what they correspond to.

Comment: To do it the way you describe you'd basically have to write some kind of custom JSON parser. Unless you have good reasons (e.g. the JSON file is huge to be stored in RAM) I recommend you just decode it as JavaScript array using the builtin parser, operate on that and decode again when done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build a reference for the old keys and the new keys and iterate the array and the keys. Then assign to new property and delete the old property.

```js
var keynames = [{ FieldID: 7, FieldName: "Emp ID", IsSortableInput: 0, IsFilterableInput: 0, ViewAlias: "EmpID", LogicOperator: "IN", AllowMultipleValues: 1, IsViewable: 1, PrimaryOnly: 0, DisplayOrder: 1 }, { FieldID: 3, FieldName: "QID", InputTypeID: 1, FieldPlaceholder: "Enter Employee Name", IsSortableInput: 1, IsFilterableInput: 1, ViewAlias: "QID", LogicOperator: "IN", AllowMultipleValues: 1, IsViewable: 1, PrimaryOnly: 0, DisplayOrder: 2, FieldTypeDesc: "PeopleSearch" }, { FieldID: 6, FieldName: "NTID", IsSortableInput: 1, IsFilterableInput: 0, ViewAlias: "NTID", LogicOperator: "IN", AllowMultipleValues: 1, IsViewable: 1, PrimaryOnly: 0, DisplayOrder: 3 }],
    source = [{ _3: "Q123", _7: "E12345" }, { _3: "X123", _7: "E34567" }],
    reference = {};

keynames.forEach(function (o) {
    reference['_' + o.FieldID] = o.FieldName;
});

source.forEach(function (o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        o[reference[k]] = o[k];
        delete o[k];
    });
});

console.log(source);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Once JSON file has been parsed, I would use:

> delete key.name

then recreate a key with desired value, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
var source = [
        {"_3": "Q123", "_7": "E12345"},
        {"_3": "X123","_7": "E34567"}
    ],
    translationTable = [
        {
        "FieldID": "7",
        "FieldName": "Emp ID",
        "IsSortableInput": "0",
        "IsFilterableInput": "0",
        "ViewAlias": "EmpID",
        "LogicOperator": "IN",
        "AllowMultipleValues": "1",
        "IsViewable": "1",
        "PrimaryOnly": "0",
        "DisplayOrder": "1"
        },
        {
        "FieldID": "3",
        "FieldName": "QID",
        "InputTypeID": "1",
        "FieldPlaceholder": "Enter Employee Name",
        "IsSortableInput": "1",
        "IsFilterableInput": "1",
        "ViewAlias": "QID",
        "LogicOperator": "IN",
        "AllowMultipleValues": "1",
        "IsViewable": "1",
        "PrimaryOnly": "0",
        "DisplayOrder": "2",
        "FieldTypeDesc": "PeopleSearch"
        },
        {
        "FieldID": "6",
        "FieldName": "NTID",
        "IsSortableInput": "1",
        "IsFilterableInput": "0",
        "ViewAlias": "NTID",
        "LogicOperator": "IN",
        "AllowMultipleValues": "1",
        "IsViewable": "1",
        "PrimaryOnly": "0",
        "DisplayOrder": "3"
        }
    ],
    transform = function transform( source, translationTable ) {
        // first we create a lookup table so we can reference each number directly to the key it will become.
        var nameMap = translationTable.reduce(function( map, next ) {
            var keyName = '_' + next.FieldID;
            if (!map[keyName]) map[keyName] = next.FieldName;
            return map;
        }, {});
        // loop over all the source objects, returning a new object with the correct keys.
        return source.map(function( obj ) {
            return Object.keys( obj ).reduce(function( record, keyName ) {
                record[ nameMap[ keyName ] ] = obj[ keyName ];
                return record;
            }, {});
        });
    },
    result = transform( source, translationTable );
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let mapping = [
{
    "FieldID": "7",
    "FieldName": "Emp ID",
    "IsSortableInput": "0",
    "IsFilterableInput": "0",
    "ViewAlias": "EmpID",
    "LogicOperator": "IN",
    "AllowMultipleValues": "1",
    "IsViewable": "1",
    "PrimaryOnly": "0",
    "DisplayOrder": "1"
},
{
    "FieldID": "3",
    "FieldName": "QID",
    "InputTypeID": "1",
    "FieldPlaceholder": "Enter Employee Name",
    "IsSortableInput": "1",
    "IsFilterableInput": "1",
    "ViewAlias": "QID",
    "LogicOperator": "IN",
    "AllowMultipleValues": "1",
    "IsViewable": "1",
    "PrimaryOnly": "0",
    "DisplayOrder": "2",
    "FieldTypeDesc": "PeopleSearch"
},
{
    "FieldID": "6",
    "FieldName": "NTID",
    "IsSortableInput": "1",
    "IsFilterableInput": "0",
    "ViewAlias": "NTID",
    "LogicOperator": "IN",
    "AllowMultipleValues": "1",
    "IsViewable": "1",
    "PrimaryOnly": "0",
    "DisplayOrder": "3"
}
];

let source = [
{
    "_3": "Q123",
    "_7": "E12345"
},
{
    "_3": "X123",
    "_7": "E34567"
}
];

source.map(ele => {
    let ret = {};
    Object.keys(ele).forEach(key => {
        let keyNum = key.replace('_','');
        let match = mapping.find(ele => {
            return ele.FieldID === keyNum;
        });
        ret[match.FieldName] = ele[key];
    });
    return ret;
});
```